# How to get css properties from a parsed html element using AngleSharp

Tags: c#, anglesharp, css-parsing

Having this CSS:

```css
.foo { background-size: 10px 20px; }
```

And this Html:

```html
<span class="foo"></span>
```

And this C#:

```csharp
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var doc = parser.Parse("http://localhost/test.html");
var element = doc.QuerySelector("span.foo");
```

How do I get the associated background width and height to **element**?

(Currently I'm using AngleSharp version 0.9.9)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all the C# code is wrong. The string you pass on to `parser.Parse` is an HTML code, not an URI. Also your code does not do any CSS parsing - it is only using an HTML parser. Thus let's use a browsing context to get all you need.

```
var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCss();
var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
var document = context.OpenAsync("http://localhost/test.html").Result;
var element = document.QuerySelector("span.foo");
var style = document.DefaultView.GetComputedStyle(element);
var size = style.BackgroundSize;
```

Keep in mind that `element` may be null if no such element exists (none matching the query) and that the `GetComputedStyle` method only works in a limited way. Also if your CSS is defined in an external style sheet make sure to activate resource loading.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, after a minor fix, got your code working. It just needs to add document loading support to the config like this: `var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCss();` otherwise the document body is always empty.

Comment: Yes indeed (I focused on the CSS part alone - so I skipped everything else from the config). I modified my answer. Thanks for your reminder!